# Renaming items in export menu in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Can someone please suggest if there is anyway we can rename the items in the export menu in highcharts. Currently it has entries like: 
Download PNG image
Download JPEG image
...

I want to remove word "image". Moreover want to control the complete styling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are lots of options for this. Some can be done in Javascript, and I'm sure more can be done in CSS. Here is a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/g43pqv21/) showing the desired text changes and some style changes.

You can read the details on this in the API under [lang](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang) and [navigation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#navigation).

The text is changed with:

```
lang: {
    printChart: 'Print chart',
    downloadPNG: 'Download PNG',
    downloadJPEG: 'Download JPEG',
    downloadPDF: 'Download PDF',
    downloadSVG: 'Download SVG',
    contextButtonTitle: 'Context menu'
}
```

And the style of the button and menu with:

```
navigation: {
    menuStyle: {
        border: '1px solid #A0A0A0',
        background: '#FFFFFF',
        padding: '5px 0'
    },
    menuItemStyle: {
        padding: '0 10px',
        background: null,
        color: '#303030',
        fontSize: '11px'
    },
    menuItemHoverStyle: {
        background: '#4572A5',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },

    buttonOptions: {
        symbolFill: '#E0E0E0',
        symbolSize: 14,
        symbolStroke: '#666',
        symbolStrokeWidth: 3,
        symbolX: 12.5,
        symbolY: 10.5,
        align: 'right',
        buttonSpacing: 3,
        height: 22,
        // text: null,
        theme: {
            fill: 'white', // capture hover
            stroke: 'none'
        },
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        width: 24
    }
}
```

You can get the default values from [the source code](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.src.js), almost at the very top. Some of the defaults use variables that you won't have though, so you may need to change them. And as mentioned, CSS may get you the extra distance.